# Copy array in constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, copy-constructor, constexpr

I wrote a class with a `constexpr` copy constructor. (It is a struct in example to make it simpler.) One of the fields is an array. I want copy it too.

```
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int SIZE = 4;
    constexpr Foo() = default;
    constexpr Foo(const Foo &foo) :
            arr{foo.arr[0], foo.arr[1], foo.arr[2], foo.arr[3]},
            bar(foo.bar+1) {}
    int arr[SIZE] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    int bar = 0;
};
```

My version works but it isn't scalable. If I change `SIZE`, I have to modify the constructor. In addition, code looks ugly.

Is it any better way to copy array in constructor? Constructor must be `constexpr`.

Comment: Doesn't the default copy constructor do the job?

Comment: Does not constexpr guarantee that the array will not be mutated? Why bother copy by value and not just a pointer?

Comment: @juanchopanza I honestly do not crossed my mind. But the question is the question. 
You may assume that the class contains some fields that require some calculations for copying. Besides possible that it will be in the future.

Comment: Then you should post some code that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you need some things differently from the compiler-generated copy constructor, but do want to copy each of the array's elements by value, then my suggestion would be to not use a raw array. Wrap that in a different structure instead, and use the compiler-generated copy constructor for that different structure. (In other words, use `std::array`.)

Comment: @juanchopanza As you wish.

Comment: The way to do it manually is `make_index_sequence` and delegating to a template constructor that does a pack expansion. `make_index_sequence` is C++14 but implementable in C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::array. Since it is an aggregate type I believe this will work.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would like to know how you can do it directly.

Answer (score 4):

In C++14 you can just use a loop to copy the array:

```
constexpr Foo(const Foo &foo)
    : bar(foo.bar + 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        arr[i] = foo.arr[i];
}
```

That doesn't mean you *should* do it. I'd recommend to use `std::array` instead. For example, if `arr` is an array of some class type with non-trivial initialization, it would be default-initialized and then copied, thus wasting performance, instead of copy-initialization when using `std::array` and default copy constructor.

Comment: It's not a good general approach even in C++14 though: it assigns to each array element, rather than copy-constructing each array element. That doesn't matter when it's an array of `int`, but it does matter for other types.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like in C++11 to just copy the array

```
template <int LENGTH>
constexpr bool copy_array(const char (&from)[LENGTH + 1], char (&to)[LENGTH], int index)
{
    return index < LENGTH ?  (to[index] = from[index], copy_array(from, to, ++index)) : false;
}

constexpr char src[] = "ab";
char dest[2];
copy_array(src, dest, 0);
```

edited:
And in your context, you might be able to do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int SIZE = 4;
    constexpr Foo() = default;
    constexpr Foo(const Foo &foo) :
            arr{foo.arr},
            bar(foo.bar + 1) {}
    std::array<int, SIZE> arr = {{0, 0, 0, 0}};
    int bar = 0;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Foo foo1;
    constexpr Foo foo2(foo1);

    std::cout << foo1.bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo2.bar << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you include a whole constructor definition in your example?

Comment: I tried in the context of a constexpr class constructor but it's not easy. and there's another way:  template <int LENGTH> struct Foo { template <typename... Args> constexpr Foo(Args&&... args) : data{args} {} char data[LENGTH];};